# Using multiple Authorization schemes (HMAC and OATH)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, hmac

Okay so i have a WebAPI Auth service that is used for the /token request and returns the Bearer token to the client, i have added an AppId and Api Key to the properties so i get back

```
{
"access_token": "...",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 86399,
"dm:appid": "1",
"dm:apikey": "...",
".issued": "Wed, 01 Jul 2015 20:46:45 GMT",
".expires": "Thu, 02 Jul 2015 20:46:45 GMT"
}
```

The AppId and Api Key should be used by the client to generate a Hmac SHA256 signature for each request.

On my controller i have used the Authorize attribute and created a HmacAuthentication attribute which implement IAuthenticationFilter

```
[RoutePrefix("api/account")]
[Authorize]
[HmacAuthentication]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    // rest of controller here
}
```

The issue i have is that any request to this controller will expect the `Authorization: Bearer ...` header and the HmacAuthentication attribute also expects the `Authorization: amx` header.

Now i know that you can only have one Authorization header so my quandry is how can i implement both Authorization headers without breaking HTTP, has anyone achieved the use of both OWIN OAuth and HMAC Authentication

I followed these examples from Taiseer Joudeh

[Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)
[Secure ASP.NET Web API using API Key Authentication – HMAC Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/)

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation. I'm considering just using a custom header instead of trying to make two Authorization headers work. Have you come up with something better?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a long while without an answer and since I have resolved my original issue I figured I should post the solution here so others can make use of it.

In the end, the solution was to add a custom header like @Glaucus suggested in their comment. For the standard OAuth authorisation I added the `Authorize` header attribute.  To satisfy my need for the HMAC I simply added an `X-Authorize` attribute to the header and modified my code to use this header instead.

Now I can have a WebAPI service secured by OAuth token and by implementing HMAC authorisation on the requests

Comment: Neil, be sure to heed the considerations in RFC 7235 (section 5.1.2) in regards to cache control, when using a header other than `Authorization`.